# Tensorflow: Access index of variable containing an array

Tags: tensorflow

I need to save some values to specific places in a tensorflow array:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

AVG = tf.Variable([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], name='data')

for i in range(5): 
   data = np.random.randint(1000, size=10000)
   AVG += np.average(data)
```

I need to make it average each iteration in different places of the AVG variable. Is this doable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.scatter_add`. Here is a complete working program :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

AVG = tf.Variable([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], name='data')

for i in range(5):
  data = np.random.randint(1000, size=10000)
  AVG = tf.scatter_add(AVG, [i], [np.average(data).astype('int')])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print(AVG.eval())
```